# Can I setup multi port from one web app with Go?

Tags: go

As I know, I can run simple web server with Golang just use `http` package, like

```
http.ListenAndServe(PORT, nil)
```

where PORT is TCP address to listen.

Can I use PORT as PORT**S**, for example `http.ListenAndServe(":80, :8080", nil)` from one application?

Possible my question is stupid, but "Who don't ask, He will not get answer!"

Comment: It probably would have been faster to just try: `listen tcp: too many colons in address :80, :8080`. The documentation is also pretty clear http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe

Comment: No one has brought up the fact that you should probably just be using port forwarding outside of Go.

Comment: Just for the record, you can listen on multiple ports as JimB suggester, or better, fire up different instances of your app, those that listen on different ports; then use haproxy or nginx at the front as a reverse proxy and send paths to relevant instances.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, you cannot.

You can however start multiple listeners on different ports

```
go http.ListenAndServe(PORT, handlerA)
http.ListenAndServe(PORT, handlerB)
```

Comment: `go ...` mean that I can't combine two handlers into one? Maybe is possible to create like "wrapper" over handlerA and handlerB?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking with `go ...`. You can combine handlers if you want, it's up to you. You asked if you can listen on multiple ports, and to do that you need multiple listeners.

Comment: `go` it's goroutine, right? It's mean other "thread". If it right, how I can "listen" incoming traffic to handlerA inside handlerB?

Comment: Yes, I'm not correct ask, my mistake, sorry. I need one handler to miltiple ports.

Comment: Then use the same handler; it would be easier for you to just try these out yourself. If you're unsure what a goroutine is, you really need to start here: http://golang.org/doc/

Comment: @user4611478 Goroutine != Thread. That's step 1 in your understanding of a Goroutine.

Comment: @user4611478 go routines are like threads but actually many goroutines are multiplexed into couple O.S. threads. So, they occupy less resource in computer. [In this video, co-creator of Go, Pike explains concurrency, parallelism and relevant topics in Go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oV9rvDllKEg)

Answer (score 16):

Here is a simple working Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello")
}

func world(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "world")
}

func main() {
    serverMuxA := http.NewServeMux()
    serverMuxA.HandleFunc("/hello", hello)

    serverMuxB := http.NewServeMux()
    serverMuxB.HandleFunc("/world", world)

    go func() {
        http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8081", serverMuxA)
    }()

    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8082", serverMuxB)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need different instances of `*http.Server`, each configured separately (for same or different as your choice) handlers (or routers) to serve their endpoints.

We have a better method to organize concurrent `http.Server` instances while still supporting graceful shutdown after `SIGINT` which is the signal that sent from shell to O.S. and O.S. to program when terminal user presses `ctrl+c`.

```golang
func main() {
    var serverA = &http.Server{}
    var serverB = &http.Server{}

    // ... configure them as you wish: add endpoints

    go serverA.ListenAndServe()
    go serverB.ListenAndServe()

    // create a channel to subscribe ctrl+c/SIGINT event
    sigInterruptChannel := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigInterruptChannel, os.Interrupt)
    // block execution from continuing further until SIGINT comes
    <-sigInterruptChannel
    
    // create a context which will expire after 4 seconds of grace period
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*4)
    defer cancel()
    
    // ask to shutdown for both servers
    go serverA.Shutdown(ctx)
    go serverB.Shutdown(ctx)

    // wait until ctx ends (which will happen after 4 seconds)
    <-ctx.Done()
}
```

See also:

- [`signal.Notify()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/signal#Notify)
- [`http.Shutdown(context.Context)`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Server.Shutdown)